# Setting up different roles depending on url in web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="USERS"/>
            <allow roles="ROLES"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
```

Is there a way to write an if statement in here to detect what url I am on so I can allow a certain role for that certain URL.

Example code in my head of what I kind of want to see:

```
If (UCase(Url) = UCase("URL")) Then
<allow roles="ROLES"/>
ElseIF(UCase(Url) = UCase("URL")) Then
<allow roles="ROLES"/>
ElseIF (UCase(Url) = UCase("URL")) Then
<allow roles="ROLES"/>
End If
<deny users="*"/>
```

Is this even allowed in the web.config? If it isn't how could I go about doing this?

I have 3 websites. One for Dev, UAT and PROD.  Now for each sites I have different user groups for each set up. I just want to find a way that I can just find what URL i'm at and point it at the certain user group. I'm guessing I have to make a `web.config` for each because you can't do conditional statements but I'm just making sure. If I have to make a `web.config` for each how can I go about setting that up?

Comment: What do you do for connection strings? (I'm presuming you have a different database for each app)

Comment: @davidsleeps I do have three separate connection strings set up. One for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit (changed the whole answer as I think your issue is now different)**

Your best option is to have different configuration settings in each web.config which is what web.config files are for. You might have to look at your deployment process if you deploy the web.config each time (either manually or automatically).

Another option would be to instead have your application do the authorisation by knowing what environment it is running in and denying access using code. That path is obviously more work than something that has already been provided, but is an option.

Comment: Note: instead of adding this to the main web.config file you can actually place a different web.config file in each affected subfolder with the appropriate permission demands.

Comment: @Chris, maybe I haven't read it right...Re-reading it, this would still work- unless of course he has a lot of roles and having to define them for every possible role...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (and most of the time better) you should place additional web.config files in your subfolders - then the folder itself defines who can access it.
In these web.configs all you need to have is the authentication section that will override parent folder authentication.

In general this only works properly in webforms, as MVC got rid of meaningful folders and supports different security model entirely (the one where Controller has to figure out the access via new security attributes)

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying the **same web application** to **different** environments, then you can consider using web.config transformations. With this approach you can have a special file for each environment that will take the default development web.config and change **only certain** values, in your case the `<authorization>` tag (or maybe also the `<connectionStrings>` or `<appSettings>` tags if you want to).

In Visual Studio it looks like this:

[image: web.config transform files]

*This only works for Web Application Projects, not for Web Site Projects (*), and only with Visual Studio 2010 and later.*

You need to create a solution configuration for each environment first. From the main menu, select `Build > Configuration Manager`. Here you can manage each configuration. By default you will have *Debug* and *Release*, you can add *UAT* and *Production* configurations for your solution for example.

Then you can right-click the web.config file in your Web Application project and click *Add config transforms* and you will find a new transform for each configuration:

```
web.config
  web.Debug.config
  web.Production.config
  web.Release.config
  web.UAT.config
```

Now you must write the transformation, in your case, it would look like this (for web.UAT.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <authorization xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <allow roles="USER-ACCEPTANCE-TEST" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  <system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notice how we instruct the transformation to replace the `<authorization>` tag completely. This will happen when you publish the web application (right click and select *Publish...*), for example to a folder on your desktop for transferring by FTP to the UAT server.

See here for some tutorials:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg454290
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd465318.aspx
- Although you can technically use it in a Web Site project, it's not easy. You will have to use the Visual Studio command line to run msbuild.exe. See some of the tutorial above for how to do that as well).

Comment: I should let you know I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Ah, too bad, it's a nice feature. Before this we used XSLT stylesheets to transform web.config files using a [command line processor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21714). Not as integrated in Visual Studio, although you can add it as a task to MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

Replace on your roleManager like this:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
```